# Removing all directories in a path

Tags: makefile, directory, rm

I have a makefile which lists several directories with which I need to do stuff with, e.g.

```
DIRS = dir1 dir2 path/to/dir3

all:
    $(foreach DIR,$(DIRS), somecommand --source=$(SOURCEDIR)/$(DIR) --dest=$(DIR);)

clean:
    rm -rf $(DIRS)
```

Currently the `clean` target removes `dir1`, `dir2`, and `dir3`, but I would like it to remove `dir1`, `dir2` and `path`. Something along the lines of:

```
clean:
    $(foreach DIR,$(DIRS), rm -rf --parents $(DIR);)
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such flag available to `rm`.  You could do something like this:

```
clean:
        $(foreach DIR,$(DIRS),rm -rf $(firstword $(subst /, ,$(DIR)));)
```

if you're absolutely sure that you always want to delete everything below the first directory in every path in `DIRs` (sounds dangerous to me, but...)

Comment: Only dangerous if I accidentally use an absolute path. Then again, that's only a single typo away, so in conclusion - yes, rather dangerous.

Comment: It won't be a problem for an absolute path, because the first word of that will be taken and won't be visible in your local directory.  The above ONLY works for paths that are rooted in your current working directory.  For example if you added `/usr/bin` to `DIRS` then the above would run `rm -rf usr` which would not work (presumably, unless you happened to have a `usr` local subdirectory).